# How to prove the sequence is a Cauchy Sequence

Tags: real-analysis

If a sequence is given by $S_{n+1}=S_n + S_{n-1}$ where $S_1=1$ and $S_2=2$ and we let $a_n=S_n/S_{n-1}$ for all $n \geq 2$.

How would you show that ${a_n}$ is a cauchy sequence using $|a_{m+1}-a_m| \leq  (2/3)^{2(m-1)}|a_2 - a_1|$?
[image]

This is what I'm thinking, but is this correct?

Comment: What is $w_n$ in the first equality?

Comment: oops, the $w_n$ is suppose to be $a_n$ similar for the $w_2-W_1$ it's suppose to be $a_2-a_1$.

Comment: I don't want to check your calculations (since the text is hardly readable). But this is the way to go.

Comment: Duplicate of [Show ${w_n}$ is a cauchy sequence](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2212626/show-w-n-is-a-cauchy-sequence)